# rails 7.1 debug turboframes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo

I'm trying to debug why rails 7.1 turboframes aren't being overwritten upon the controller returning the html.

I can see from the dev rails server log that the `results.turbo_stream.erb` file is being rendered but no change occurs to the webpage in the browser.

I've checked that the turbo_tags have identical names.

I can see in Chrome devtools Network that html is being returned which contains only

```
<turbo-frame id="second_frame">
  <h3>Result is here</h3>
    None found!
</turbo-frame>
```

There is a turboframe in the page with id "second_frame" already.

It would appear to me that Turbo is not processing this result payload, and if I can turn up Turbo debug it may show why not.

Is there any way of turning on debugging in Turbo to allow me to see what is being returned, or how Turbo is interpreting the returned html?

Comment: you're supposed to render an html response `results.html.erb` with a matching turbo frame.

Comment: Superb thanks Alex - that's got the webpage changing dynamically.